# Looking for a map of mythological Ancient Greece

Tags: geography, map-making, ancient-history, worldbuilding-resources

Does anyone know of a decent, detailed map of ancient Greece? I'm writing a series using Greek myth as a springboard, but I'm having a hard time on Google finding anything useful.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I mean this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greece features quite some maps of Ancient Greece. What kind of map you are looking for, which **isn't** there already?

Comment: Best possible might be: http://www.bl.uk/learning/timeline/large126360.html ("BL" is "British Library")

Answer (score 1):

How about [Google maps](http://rumsey.geogarage.com/maps/g4764067.html)?

With an overlay, of course.

[image]

There are quite a few other historical maps overlaid onto Google maps available from this [same website](http://rumsey.geogarage.com/index.html).